# Basic PHP clarification for variables on how executed/saved

Tags: php

I have the follow:

```
$sum = 10 + 10;
```

is the above line executed saved to `$sum` as 20 to use it from now on
**or** if everytime i `echo $sum`, it will run the 10+10?

Answer (score 1):

It only calculates it once to set the value of $sum.

So from then on out $sum is equal to 20.

So the 10+10 is only calculated the first time.

Comment: Does this happen with Javascript also? `var sum = 10+ 10 ......... document.write(sum)` ?

Comment: yes, I can't think of a language that doesn't do this

Answer (score 1):

During the lifetime of the script the value of 10 + 10 will be assigned to the $sum variable - no further 10 + 10 will be calculated when using $sum.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not inherently lazy nor it has lazy primitives, so value assignation is executed immediately. To simulate some sort of lazy functionality you can declare a function:

```
funciton sumTen() {
  return 10 + 10;
}

sumTen() // will calculate the value every time.
```

Comment: Does this happen with Javascript also? `var sum = 10+ 10 ......... document.write('sum')` ?

Comment: Javascript is also not inherently lazy nor it has lazy primitives, but you can use the same approach, languages I know which are either inherently lazy or have lazy primitives are Scala, Haskell, SML and many other functional languages.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sum = 0;

echo $sum; // will print 0

$sum = 10 + 10;

echo $sum; // will print 20

$sum = 5;

echo $sum; // will print 5
```

Comment: Does this happen with Javascript also? `var sum = 10+ 10 ......... document.write(sum)` ?